# My issue: 併用可能? What should we translate this?

Tags: meaning

Full text: テレメトリ機能: 本体は、Bluetoothを用いて、xxxxxxxxnk Heart, xxxxxxxxnk Relay、患者アシスタント及び併用可能なプログラマと双方向通信を行う。

My issue: 併用可能? What should we translate this? I could come up with programmers that can be used together / combinable programmers. This appears quite a few times in the whole text.

My understanding: Telemetry function: The main unit uses Bluetooth for two-way communication with xxxxxxxxxnk Heart, xxxxxxxxnk Relay, patient assistants, and compatible programmers/ programmers that can be used together.

Comment: プログラマ? Isn't it プログラム?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

プログラマ ("programmer") refers to humans who do programming, and humans cannot communicate with machines via Bluetooth. I believe it's a typo for プログラム ("program").

併用可能な does mean "that can be used together", and there's not much to say about this word in isolation. If this appears many times, check the first instance to see its definition. What type of program is it? What can this program can work with? Maybe you can choose to translate the phrase to "the combinable components" or even "the compatible apps", but it depends on how it has been used in the docs.